# Which brand should I go with if I want to scan my artworks?

Tags: scanner

I've shortlisted 3 entry level scanners of my budget.

1. Epson Perfection V39
2. Canon LIDE 400
3. Canon Canoscan LIDE 400

I'm not really sure if **LIDE 400** and **Canoscan LIDE 400** are same or different, but I couldn't find any difference other than dimensions and a sticker printed on one of them.

Canon India refused to tell if both are same and different. They were saying both are same. Only one of them is listed on Canon India website (i.e., **Canon LIDE 400**) They said contact Amazon. Amazon told me that both have different sellers and seller is sending under different name. But the **MRP** price difference of **Canoscan** is almost double on Amazon.

But anyway, I did my research and I couldn't find single difference between them. Because I was able to find **Canoscan** on Canon UK website and its specifications were same. **So I am assuming they are same just sold under different names.** I don't have proof though.

Now, all 3 have almost similar specifications. Same sensor, same DPI and same document size.

I didn't go into extreme details but I compared basic details which I should know and which I understand.

Now I can't make a decision. The thing is, on Amazon India, Epson V39 has better reviews. Canon LIDE 400 has a bit less good reviews. However, like I had said, Canoscan LIDE 400 is also listed on Amazon India, which has better reviews.

So overall, I feel people are doubtful about **Canon LIDE 400** or **Canoscan LIDE 400**.

Which makes me feel V39 is better. I read many articles/videos online, which also listed LIDE 400 slightly better than V39.

---

What I would scan is mostly A4 size pencil drawings on Bristol paper. Or A5 paper. Sometimes A3 paper (I know A3 is not supported but I would use multiple scans and later combine them). So main focus is A4 drawings. On rare occasions, colored photos and maybe paintings.

So is there any other criteria which I can use whether to go with Epson or Canon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your **LIDE 400** and **Canoscan LIDE 400**.
They are probably the same, but have different names since the seller forgot to type the full name and omitted "Canoscan" from "LIDE 400".

I would go with Canon since they also make cameras and that expertise might go into their scanners. They probably both perform the same if they are the same price since scanners are a commodity item and are not obscuring their quality with luxury pricing.